Simple Ngx-Charts leaving too much gap on both sides of X-axis
I have an ngx-material vertical stacked chart and my data is very simple, yet i find that for slightly larger data sets, a large gaps shows up on both sides of the x-axis labels.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Here is a visual:

And here is a stackblitz with my simple example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-stacked-vertical-bar-chart-hvkbtb?file=app%2Fdata.ts

You are not doing anything wrong.
It's a scaling problem when you have a lot of ticks on the X-axis. You can see the difference if you will change the view size from 700x500 to 1000x500.

Similar request was already made and it has open status:
github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1472
